# How to remove duplicated results of regular expression (re) in Python

Tags: python, expression

There is a string:

```
str = 'Please Contact Prof. Zheng Zhao: <a href="mailto:zheng.z@xxx.com">Zheng.Z@xxx.com</a> for details, or our HR: john.will@xxx.com'
```

I wanted to parse all of the email in that string, so I set:

```
p = r'[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+'
re.findall(p, str)
```

And the result was:

```
['zheng.z@xxx.com', 'Zheng.Z@xxx.com', 'john.will@xxx.com']
```

Apparently, the first and the second are duplicated. How do we prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove duplicates using a `set`. A `set` is like an unordered `list` which can't contain duplicates. In this case, you don't care about case, so making the results lowercase will let you properly check for duplicates.

```
import re

s = 'Please Contact Prof. Zheng Zhao: <a href="mailto:zheng.z@xxx.com">Zheng.Z@xxx.com</a> for details, or our HR: john.will@xxx.com'

p = r'[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+'
list(set(result.lower() for result in re.findall(p, s)))
```

Comment: Note - If you are also concerned about the order of the match that occurred in the string, use list(dict.fromkeys(list(result.lower() for result in re.findall(p, s))))